# Continuity of an "SVD" operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, continuity, matrix-calculus, svd

Let $A_n$ be a series of matrices, and let $A$ be another matrix.
Let $S(B)$ be an SVD operator that takes a matrix and returns the left singular vectors matrix ordered by largest singular value to smallest singular value. Also, assume all singular values for $A$ are unique.

Is there some matrix norm $\| \cdot \|$ under which if $\|A_n - A\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then $\|S(A_n) - S(A)\| \to 0$?

Does it happen for the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Even if all the singular values are unique, the singular vectors are only unique up to factors of $\pm 1$. So if $S(\cdot)$ is some numerical routine that returns a matrix it could be discontinuous. Other than that, it's continuous. And it doesn't matter what norm you use; since matrices are finite dimensional, all norms are equivalent for purposes of continuity.

Comment: in what sense "other than that" it is continuous? What is the right definition of the SVD operator to make it continuous (even when the singular values are not unique)?

Comment: I only commented because I wasn't sure. =) As the Robert Israel's answer shows, any matrix-valued function S(A) can't be continuous. However, I believe that the singular spaces are continuous on the grassmanian manifold.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to make the operator continuous.  Consider the positive semidefinite matrices 
$$ A(t) = \pmatrix{\cos^2(t) & \cos(t) \sin(t)\cr \cos(t) \sin(t) & \sin^2(t)\cr}$$
which have eigenvalues (and singular values) $1$ and $0$.  The normalized left singular vector for singular value $1$ is $\pm [\cos(t), \sin(t)]$. To make this   vector a continuous 
function of $t$, you must take either $[\cos(t), \sin(t)]$ for all $t$ or $[-\cos(t), -\sin(t)]$ for all $t$, resulting in the vector at $t=\pi$ being 
the negative of the vector at $t=0$.  But $A(\pi) = A(0)$, so this can't happen.

Comment: not sure I understand. If we find $\{ t_n \}$ such that $||A(t_n) - A||$ converges to 0 for some $A$ as $n$ goes to infinity, I think we will have continuity of the SVD operator?

Comment: $A(t)$ is a continuous function of $t \in [0,1]$.  But $S(A(t))$ can't be a continuous function of $t$.  If $t_0$ is some point where $S(A(t))$ is discontinuous, there will be a sequence $t_n \to t_0$ such that $S(A(t_n))$ does not converge to $S(A(t_0))$ as $n \to \infty$.