# How does additive noise change the SVD

Tags: svd, random-matrices

For matrix $M$ with SVD $M=U\Sigma V^*$ and random matrix $A$, what is the SVD of $M+A$?

That is, how will $A$ change the singular values and vectors of $M$? Let's even say that the entries of $A$ are i.i.d from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/86826/27978.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870816/singular-vector-of-random-gaussian-matrix

Comment: See the discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111827/singular-value-decomposition-of-noisy-matrices. A very thorough reference is R. J. Muirhead (1982) Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory. John Wiley & Sons Inc., New York.

Answer (score 1):

First the simplest case, 1d spectra:
$\qquad M = U \, S \, V$ + Gaussian noise, symmetrized, with $U = V = I $
$\qquad = O \, S_{noise} \, O^T$

How can one compare an arbitrary
[spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum)
$S$ with its blurred / transmogrified $S_{noise}$ ?
In the real world there are many many kinds of noise,
and many ways of comparing even 1d functions $S()$ and $S_{noise}()$
of time (time series) or frequency:
weighting large or small errors, hard or soft thresholding, different norms ...

---

A simple, runnable experiment: how does noise affect
[Low-rank approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) ?
The Eckart-Young theorem says that the $k$-term series $A_k$ from SVD
$\qquad A = \sum \sigma_i \, u_i \, v_i^T $
$\qquad \ \ = A_k + Err_k $
$\qquad \ \ \ \ A_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_i \, u_i \, v_i^T $
is optimal, both in the spectral and Frobenius norms.
Let's see how $\|Err_k\|$ falls off with $k$. Pseudocode:

```
Tallnoisy = noisyUSV( n, d, rank, S, noise )  # e.g. 1000 x 100, rank 10
    = U S V + Gaussian( sigma=noise )
    U Gaussian 1000 x 10
    S = linspace( 1, 1/10, 10 )
    V random orthogonal rows 10 x 100

AA = Tallnoisy.T dot Tallnoisy  # covariance 100 x 100, pos def
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh( AA )  # evals = sing(Tallnoisy)^2
```

[image]
The quite linear fall-off of $\|Err_k\|$ with $k$ surprised me; ymmv.

---

See also
[how-much-regularization-to-add-to-make-svd-stable](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26763/how-much-regularization-to-add-to-make-svd-stable) on scicomp.stack:

> If two symmetric matrices are approximately the same, then should
>   we expect their canonical eigendecompositions to also be approximately the same?
>   The answer is a surprising no ...
>   there is no way to make the SVD "stable" in the sense of the singular vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Given the wide variety of results available on the subject,
I doubt that any sigle answer would be completely to your satisfaction.
A good place to start,
however,
would be to read the following papers:

1. G. W. Stewart, *Perturbation Theory for the Singular Value Decomposition*, SVD AND SIGNAL PROCESSING, II: ALGORITHMS, ANALYSIS AND APPLICATIONS, p. 99-100 (1990). ([Link](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/552/4/CS-TR-2539.pdf))
2. Ilse CF Ipsen, *Relative perturbation results for matrix eigenvalues and singular values*, Acta Numerica 7, p. 151-201 (1998). (Especially section 3, see [link](http://www.ncsu.edu/crsc/reports/ftp/crsc-tr97-24.ps.gz))
3. REN-CANG LI, *RELATIVE PERTURBATION THEORY:
   I. EIGENVALUE AND SINGULAR VALUE VARIATIONS*,
   SIAM J. MATRIX ANAL. Vol. 19, No. 4, p. 956–982 (1998). ([Link](http://www.uta.edu/faculty/rcli/papers/relpthyI.pdf))

In the above papers,
most of the bounds on the difference between the singular values of $M$ and $M+A$ are given in terms of $\|A\|$ or a function of $\|A\|$,
where $\|\cdot\|$ is some matrix norm.
Thus,
you would probably also be interested in bounds and estimates for the norm of random matrices.
Such results are fairly easy to find:
For example, by typing "norm of random matrices" in google,
one of the first 10 results is [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-05/S0002-9939-04-07800-1/S0002-9939-04-07800-1.pdf) paper.