# Perturbations on SVD left singular matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, svd

Given a symmetric matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, with all the entries greater than zero $A_{i,j}>0$ with rank $k<n$, we can calculate its SVD decomposition:

$$
A = USU'
$$

Assuming now that $A$ is equal to $A_T + \Delta$ where also $A_T$ is a matrix with the same properties of $A$ (real, symmetric, all positive terms, rank $k$) and $\Delta$ is a perturbation of $A_T$, we would have that

$$
A_T = U_TS_TU_T'
$$

I am interested in understanding in which conditions the following implication holds

$$
|| \Delta || \to 0  \Rightarrow ||U-U_T||\to 0 
$$

I know that in the general case this implication might not be true, but I am interested in the case when this actually holds.
Here [Continuity of an "SVD" operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86826/continuity-of-an-svd-operator) there is an example where the implication does not hold. However I found this paper

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265186583_Perturbation_analysis_of_the_eigenvector_matrix_and_singular_vector_matrices

where actual perturbations bound are provided, so I am confused..

Answer (score 1):

First, I have to emphasise that $A=USU^t$ is, in general, not a SVD. It is a symmetric eigenvalue decomposition.

For all practical purposes, the assertion
$$
\|U-U_T\| \rightarrow  \;\;\; \mbox{as} \;\;\; \|\Delta\| \rightarrow 0
$$
is true. However, one has to be careful when the eigenvectors are not uniquely defined. As an example, any orthogonal matrix $U$, $U^tU = I$  where $I$ an identity matrix is an
eigenvector matrix of the identity matrix $I$. In that case, as $\Delta$ goes to zero,  solution might migrate to a different (but valid) eigenvector matrix. This cannot happen if the eigenvectors are unique.
However, note that if $x$ is a normalised eigenvector then $-x$ is also an eigenvector.